# Assign Rank/Rating using multiple columns in Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
                                    UserId
TechnicianId    JobId   Status  
1296.0          10113   Completed   1296.0
                10131   Completed   1296.0
                10132   Assigned    121.0
                        Completed   242.0
                10133   Assigned    2633.0
                        Completed   1296.0
1316.0          10113   Assigned    968.0
                        Completed   1089.0
                        Issued      363.0
```

I have this dataframe.

Now to this dataframe, I need to assign a rank/rating to the every Job of technician based on his completition status.

I'm new to this. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What's your expected outcome?

Comment: To get an average rating for each jobs based on the jobs that technician completed.

Comment: You should provide an explicit outcome corresponding to each row, e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1]`.